# When did Kolmogorov complexity begin being applied to real world objects and ideas?

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, kolmogorov

I was looking at this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1576418?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) about "Low complexity art" which involves kolmogorov complexity and I was wondering of when did that complexity theory began being applied to other things that aren't purely mathematical.

Comment: From the beginning? [Solomonoff's 1960 report](http://world.std.com/~rjs/rayfeb60.pdf) already talked about extrapolating text passages and curve fitting for a list of temperatures. [Wallace and Boulton](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/11/2/185/378628) applied it to statistical classification in 1968.